# Trouble installing Hive on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I am attempting to install Hive on my Ubuntu machine, and using the following link as a guide. I am having trouble running step 4 in the guide.

http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu/

I suppose I have Hadoop installed correctly. The error I receive when I try creating the warehouse directory is the following:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /hduser/hive/warehouse
15/07/04 09:16:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/hduser/hive/warehouse': No such file or directory
```

A question I have is: should the hive folder folder be created before calling the -mkdir in HDFS?

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `whoami` results in terminal?

Comment: whoami returns hduser

Comment: You are running as correct user. Post result for `hadoop fs -ls /`

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to create multi level folders there.

Use `-p`

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /hduser/hive/warehouse
```

Or you can also create higher level folders first.